# How to block FIN-WAIT-2 by iptables?

Tags: iptables, ddos

My site now is under ddos-attack, "ss -ant" shows a lot of **FIN-WAIT-2** (and some **FIN-WAIT-1**) connections from one ip (and random ports), about 500-700 connections:

```
FIN-WAIT-2 0      0         ::ffff:MY_IP:443                 ::ffff:ATTACKERS_IP:RANDOM_PORT   
.... 500-700 times
```

Im trying to use

```
iptables -A INPUT -s ATTACKERS_IP -j DROP
```

and

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
echo "2" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
```

but it doesnt help - new connections are coming in with another random ports.

So, how to TOTALLY block specific IP by iptables (or maybe something else) to prevent FIN-WAIT-2 flood by ip which freezes the server?

Answer (score 2):

As explained on https://benohead.com/blog/2013/07/21/tcp-about-fin_wait_2-time_wait-and-close_wait/ (See below)

TCP fin-wait1 and finwait2 are connections that are closing from normal tcp closures. They hang around for a timer called 2 MSL (Maximum Segment Life), which is often 4 minutes on servers with default configs. They are not harmful in themselves, but if there are a lot of them, it indicates there is a lot of connection churn on the server. This can be from a DDOS attack, or a problem with the site such as turning off http keepalives. Usually DDOS attacks do not close the socket, but leave it hanging.

If there is one IP that is hammering you, then dropping that IP is the best method, preferably at a firewall or upstream router to keep the load off the system.

Fin-wait1 is the first step of an active close (four-way handshake) was performed. The local end-point has sent a connection termination request to the remote end-point.

Your rule looks correct, are there others before it that allow connections that the rule should block? You can check the list of rules and the counters with

```
iptables -nvL --line-numbers
iptables -t raw -nvL --line-numbers
```

I would change the rule to use the PREROUTING chain to drop them earlier

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -s ATTACKERS_IP -j DROP
```

You can clean up timw_waits a faster by modifying your sysctl variables. Not knowing your setup, I would only suggest these two to close then in 10 seconds and if needed, to reuse sockets that are in timewait that have not timed out

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=10
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
```

Hope that helps

FIN-WAIT-1: The first step of an active close (four-way handshake) was performed. The local end-point has sent a connection termination request to the remote end-point.

FIN-WAIT-2: The remote end-point has sent an acknowledgement for the previously sent connection termination request. The local end-point waits for an active connection termination request from the remote end-point

Comment: Some small remarks: if the connections are stuck in `FIN_WAIT_2` means the server tried to close the connection, but the client left it hanging. Also `PREROUTING` should not be used for dropping packets and it only works for new connections.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! Attack is stopped now, i think, it will be started some later again - and i will try you commands.

"Also PREROUTING should not be used for dropping packets and it only works for new connections." - so, how to kill current connections? Or they must be killed by timeout?

Comment: there's no filter/PREROUTING. there's a missing table parameter to specify: either *-t nat* (works only on first packet, so might not be useful) or *-t mangle* (works on every packet) (ok there's also *-t raw*). Simply use INPUT if not routing, but use `-I` to insert the rule before other rules

Comment: A.B thank you!! The problem has been resolved! Yes, using -I helps me, now rules works :)

Comment: A couple of corrections, prerouting is the first chain in the filter structure. It is done before a routing decision is made and reduces load on the server by killing the incoming connection before it uses many resources. Another common use is to drop packets with invalid flags such as syn/rst and the like. There is an excellent description and diagram here  https://askubuntu.com/questions/579231/whats-the-difference-between-prerouting-and-forward-in-iptables. As ab stated, this only works on new connections.

Existing connections need to timeout, which the the IPTables rules will not affect